# Dialogflow upload training phrases with entities using the Python Client

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

In my Dialogflow project, I'm uploading my training phrases in batches using the Python client [library](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?#managing-intents), in particular, as follows:

```
training_phrases = []
for training_phrases_part in training_phrases_parts:
    part = dialogflow.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(
        text=training_phrases_part)
    # Here we create a new training phrase for each provided part.
    training_phrase = dialogflow.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase(parts=[part])
    training_phrases.append(training_phrase)
```

However, in addition to the training phrases themselves, I wonder if it's also possible to upload the entities tagged inside the phrases. For example, say I have a training phrase that is "I like apples," within which, "apples" is tagged as an entity. How do I pass that information to Dialogflow along with the phrase? I understand I can always just manually highlight the entities in the UI, but I'm curious to see if there is a programmatic way of doing that using the client library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When using the API, you have to annotate the training phrases manually by splitting the entities and the rest of the phrase into different parts, roughly like this:

```
from dialogflow_v2.types import Intent

parts = [
    Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(text='I like '),  # Note the space at the end, you have to add them manually
    Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(text='apples', entity_type='@fruit:fruit')
]
training_phrase = Intent.TrainingPhrase(parts=parts)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked although for `entity_type`, I think you need to separate alias out of it. This worked for me: `Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(text='apples', entity_type='@fruit', alias='fruit')`

Comment: Oh sorry, I had overlooked that.